# Yocto fido ->morty update dnsmasq NO GNU_HASH

Tags: yocto, ldflags

So, I was given the task to upgrade our yocto based system from fido to morty. I have very little experience with yocto, I have been struggling with it and trying to understand it for almost a week now. I have managed to fix some issues, but now I'm facing a problem when trying to build the image:

```
dnsmasq-2.68-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: No GNU_HASH in the elf binary: '/oe/.../dnsmasq/2.68-r0/packages-split/dnsmasq/usr/bin/dnsmasq'
```

I have looked online for a solution and I did find a way to suppress the error by adding:

```
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "ldflags"
```

in the recipe.

However I don't believe this is the 'correct' way to do it, and I had it on another recipe, that had the same problem. I also found that someone had similar issue and rearranging packages did the trick, but I don't know how to do that.

So my question is: Is it bad idea to just add the insane_skip to all recipes that have this issue and if so how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd likely benefit from having a look at the [`dnsmasq`](http://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-networking/recipes-support/dnsmasq?h=morty) recipe in `meta-oe`.

Your problem is that `dnsmasq` doesn't respect the `LDFLAGS` variable out of the box. Try adding:

```
EXTRA_OEMAKE_append = " 'LDFLAGS=${LDFLAGS}'"
```

to your recipe. (See the recipe in the linked URL).

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. But why is this an issue now, when I moved to morty, but not an issue in fido?

Comment: Unless you have followed the development cycles closely, always check out the migration guide in the Yocto Project Reference Manual. This particular change is coverd in http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.2.1/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#migration-2.2-default-linker-hash-style-changed.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, you might have overridden EXTRA_OECONF with `EXTRA_OECONF = " foobar "`.
Use the **`+=`** notion might resolve the issue:

```
EXTRA_OECONF += " foobar "
```